# Regex: Sentence Beginning With Keyword Ending with Sentence Blank Output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I was to print "m," there would be a result that begins with "Histology" and ends with a period. Despite that, the output shows up empty.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googlesearch import search 
import requests
from goose3 import Goose
def search_google(query):
    parent_=[]  
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=5, pause=2):
        child_=[]
        link_=j
        site_name=link_.split("/")[2]
        child_.append(site_name)
        child_.append(link_)
        parent_.append(child_)  
        g = Goose()
        article = g.extract(link_)
        m = article.cleaned_text
    Answer = re.findall(r'\bHistology\s+([^.]*)',m)  
    print(Answer)

f = search_google("""'Histology'""")
```

Output: []

Comment: Could you provide part of `m` containing `Histology`. Currently your regex will only match if there is at least one space between `Histology` and the `.`

Comment: @PacketLoss Sure. "Histology is the study of the microanatomy of cells, tissues, and organs as seen through a microscope."

Comment: What do you want to match in this string?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. That is only the sentence that matches the structure. What I wish to recieve as an output would be all the sentences that begin with "Histology." For example, the second sentence here should be excluded: "Histology is the study of the microanatomy of cells, tissues, and organs as seen through a microscope. It examines the correlation between structure and function."

Comment: Do you need the word `Histology` to be returned for every sentence, or just the sentence?

Comment: @PacketLoss I'd like for that to be the case, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `answer` variable has incorrect indentation, and your last result has no matches in the cleaned text. This is why your print results in a empty list.

The print command, since it sits outside of the loop only triggers once. And given the final value of `Answer` has no matches, you are returned an empty list.

Indent the `answer` variable by 1 and it should output the correct result.

Your regex will also only match the sentence following `Histology` and not include the word itself. This is due to you specifying a capture group without `Histology` included. You can resolve this by removing the capturing group.

`r'\bHistology\s+[^.]*'`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googlesearch import search 
import requests
from goose3 import Goose
def search_google(query):
    parent_=[]  
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=5, pause=2):
        child_=[]
        link_=j
        site_name=link_.split("/")[2]
        child_.append(site_name)
        child_.append(link_)
        parent_.append(child_)  
        g = Goose()
        article = g.extract(link_)
        m = article.cleaned_text
        Answer = re.findall(r'\bHistology\s+[^.]*',m)  
        print(Answer)


f = search_google("""'Histology'""")
```

To print all results on individual lines you can change `print(Answer)` to `print('\n'.join(Answer))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry to ask this question, but do you know how I could return the text vertically? Example: Histology.... \n Histology.... \n. Whenever I do replace, it does not work.

Comment: You want to return results for every single search in a single list?

Comment: I may have explained my thinking bad. I would like to return a new line for each result, but replacing "." with ". \n" has proven not to work.

Comment: Do you want this printed to the console or returned as data you can access later?

Comment: Thank you for your continued responses. I'd like to the console.

Comment: Edited answer to include at the bottom.